# Angular 5 Date Validation (accepted min and max)

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I cant seem to find a simple solution to this but I have a date input like so..

```
<input [(ngModel)]="toolDate" type="text" class="tool_input tool_input__date">
```

now Im using https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/ to control the input so you cant write anything but a date so In my app.component.ts

```
export class ...
   toolDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');

ngOnInit() {
    const cleave = new Cleave('.tool_input__date', {
      date: true,
      datePattern: ['d', 'm', 'Y']
    });
}
```

so I don't need date format validation but I do need min and max date validation.. so a user cant type in less than say 01/01/2017 and cant enter a date past the current date

now I know that by default you can use date and set a min and max but I don't want to use the default html date picker

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You can use angular material date picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as following to validate the date by using custom function.

HTML

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="myDate">
```

Component :
validation while buiding form group

```
this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    'myDate': new FormControl('myDateVal', [Validators.required, isValidDate]),
});
```

Utility Method to validate date.

```
export const isValidDate = (c: FormControl) => {
  const DATE_REGEXP = /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/;
  return DATE_REGEXP.test(c.value) || c.value === '' ? null : {
    validateDate: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}
```